Dfference between orthogonal decomposition and method of separation of variables
Jackson, preface to ch 2, claims there is a difference between expansion of boundary/potential in orthogonal functions, and separation of variables. At face value, this is of course true. However, in practice, the orthogonal sets of functions we end up using are the family of solutions to our separated ODE's. In my weak understanding of orthogonal functions, I believe most of the ones we use derive from Strum-Louisville, so the relation between separated ODEs and functional basis is to be expected.
Jackson does not seem to ever draw any distinction between the two as "separate methods" again in chapter 2, as far as I can tell. Additionally, he does not expand on what he means by using orthogonal functions to solve problems. He uses orthogonal functions, but only in after separating the variables.
Thus, my question is: In the context of electrodynamics, is there a useful distinction between the two methods? If so, when and how, in broad strokes, should I be using orthogonal decomp?

Yes the distinction is very relevant in EM. Separation of variables is more general. A typical case where the two are different is when you have dissipation at the boundary. In this case separation of variables gives you a basis that is typically not orthonormal.
Consider for example a waveguide with resistors at the end, given by the telegrapher's equation:
$$
\partial_tu +\partial_xi=0\quad \partial_ti+\partial_xu = 0
$$
with boundary conditions:
$$
u = -ri \quad (x=0) \\
u = ri \quad (x=1)
$$
You can automatically get one equation by using the gauge field:
$$
u = -\partial_t\phi \quad i = \partial_x\phi
$$
giving you the usual d'Alembert equation:
$$
\partial_t^2\phi-\partial_x^2\phi = 0
$$
You can now solve it by separation of variables. You do recover a basis, but it is not orthonormal anymore. The same thing happens in higher dimensions.
